# Closed mesh has weird artifacts (Blender Guru Anvil Tutorial)

Tags: modeling, artifacts

I'm making an anvil and while the wireframe of the mesh looks fine, there are weird artifacts near the base of the anvil that I can't seem to get rid of (I tried recalculate normals and merge by distance).

The problem is exacerbated in lookDev, where I'm getting an odd, swirled stretching effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices). Try to avoid that, especially on twisted surfaces. Just join the vertices with <kbd>J</kbd> to make quads.

[image]

You also have faces overlapping like these ones. Delete them but also the ones underneath because sometimes the face is large as 2 faces. Here again make sure that you have quads.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to **moonboots**'s answer, make sure to disable the *Subsurf* modifier for the Edit Mode, otherwise you'll have a hard time fixing your mesh.

[image]

Another issue is that your normals are mostly inverted. Enable `Face orientation` in the Overlays menu, as shown below; then, in edit mode, make sure all the faces are coloured blue. You can change a face's colour (that is, their normal's orientation) by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> > *Flip*.
(*N.b.* You can flip multiple face's normals at once).

[image]

Comment: Edit: the keyboard shortcut for the normals menu is alt + N.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Edited it.